# Showing MVC validation error next to the element

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using the @Html.ValidationMessageFor helper method for validation but the messages are displayed only when I declare Html.ValidationSummary. 
Is there a way to show the error messages next to the elements instead of a Validation summary?

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Registration Form</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { id = "registerName" })
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
            <div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
            <div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" value="Sign up" />
        </li>
    </ol>
    @*@Html.ValidationSummary()*@
</fieldset>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Put some example code

Comment: Code posted. 
Only when the ValidationSummary is present (not marked as comment) the messages are shown

Comment: Have you include `unobtrusive` and `validate` scripts in your page

Comment: could you post complete code along with Form?

Comment: I have included these scripts. This is the intranet template in visual studio. I just commented the validation summary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Yaron,

Looking at your code, it all looks good. You don't need the Validation Summary for the validation to work correctly. But you do need the jQuery libraries included.

If you look at a stock Internet MVC Application, you will see at the bottom of the Login page this code:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

This will access the jqueryval bundle from the BundleConfig file in the App_Start folder. Assuming you have all of these in your application, that block of code should fix your problem.

Comment: Oh! What an embarrassment! I didn't notice that these scripts are rendered only when the user is authenticated so all the validations before that are not displayed as intended!!! LOL. Thanks!

Comment: No problem at all. Glad I could help you out. If you found my answer helpful, please take a moment to +1 my answer. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have enough reputation yet.. sorry mate

Comment: Try now :) I helped you out a bit.